# TwitterService.getAccessToken errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tweetsharp

I am trying to use tweetSharp in an ASP MVC 3 application. I am using the code in the example from https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp. I have been able to use the desktop example using a c# WPF application successfully so I don't think it is the keys I am using. It returns a 500 error when it goes to this line of my code in the authorizeCallback controller method:

`OAuthAccessToken accessToken = service.GetAccessToken(requestToken, oauth_verifier);`

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this and how to fix it?